# SSIS assign value to variable to be used as Filter in copying file

Tags: ssis

How can I achieve this, filterFileName = "MyFilter_" + "date" + "*.csv"? 
date variable stores value in this format = 12202015.
Is it even possible? How can I assign a value to a SSIS variable which will be used as filter when copying or moving file to another folder.
Or is my approach correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable combining other variables defined in your solution. I normally name my output files using the following:
VarFileName: A string variable containing the base filename
varFilePath: A string variable containing the base file path
These can be updated via a config file or by obtaining filenames from a For..Each loop container

```
varFilepath+varFilename+varDate+”.csv”


varDate =
(dt_wstr,4)(datepart("yy",getdate()) ) + (dt_wstr,2)(datepart("mm",getdate()))
+ (dt_wstr,2)(datepart("dd",getdate()) )+ (dt_wstr,2(datepart("hh",getdate()))
+ (dt_wstr,2)(datepart("n",getdate()) )+(dt_wstr,2)(datepart("ss",getdate()))
```

You can use the FileSystem object to move/rename/delete this file

Comment: How about with this one, I'm trying to get the number of column header in excel file through script task. I want to check if it matches with the sql table column and then rename certain column header in excel file before copying.

Comment: Hi @r-r.I think you would be better off asking a new question for this!